# Android Implicit Intents with custom mimeType

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, mime-types, implicit

I am getting an ActivityNotFound exception with a call like this:

```
Intent displayModule = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        displayModule.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        displayModule.setType("application/x-content");
        displayModule.putExtra(Modules.Plan_ID, holder.planId);
        displayModule.putExtra(Modules.Module_ID, holder.moduleId);
        startActivity(displayModule);
```

Adding the default category doesn't make a difference.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/x-content (has extras) }
```

or

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] typ=application/x-content (has extras) }
```

when I am trying to reference this activity:

```
<activity android:name=".ContentActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="application/x-content" />
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Additionally, if it helps I am doing this in a Fragment**

Comment: show me your call to start activity

Comment: I had the included the lines from logcat at the top for that reason. Anyways, I had updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's the enclosing `action` tag

try this please :

```
<activity android:name=".ContentActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/x-content" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```